# can i store json data in array everytime that i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

when I go back in previous route I get an error in this line
`meals = data.meals.map(meal => meal);`:

> Type Error, Cannot read property 'map' of null

```
request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response.body);

    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        const meals = data.meals.map(meal => meal);
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        res.render("result", { categories: meals, title: category });
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: What is in the `response`? `data` doesn't appear to contain `meals`.

Comment: the response is json data which is the list of categories/meals